# EF6 Code First - Informing EF that a non-nullable scalar need not be emitted as there is a DEFAULT VALUE CONSTRAINT defined

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have an EF Code First design.  One of our Entities has a DateTime column, not-nullable.  We've added a DEFAULT VALUE CONSTRAINT via the Migration:

`AddColumn( "dbo.MyTable", "WhenUpdated", c => c.DateTime( nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"));`

The corresponding `MyTable` entity looks like this:

```
public class MyTable
{
...
    public DateTime WhenUpdated {get; set; }
....
}
```

I hand added in the extra `defaultValueSql` parameter to `AddColumn`...so EF may not "know" about it if it's relying on the generated EDMX.

EF tries to flow a value for the `WhenUpdated` property whenever we call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` and an instance of `MyTable` is dirty -- even / especially when we've not assigned a value to `WhenUpdated`.

I know that I can change the datatype of `WhenUpdated` from `DateTime` to `System.Nullable<DateTime>` so that EF Migrations detects that the column should be nullable ... but am wondering if there's something else I can do in an `DbContext.OnModelCreating` override to inform EF that it need not pass `WhenUpdated` unless it has a non-default value.

I guess I'm looking for the EF equivalent of the T-SQL Stored Procedure default-parameter-value...where I could default a sproc `@parameter` to something like `GETUTCDATE()` so that a caller didn't have to pass in a value.

Comment: Funny you should mention that last bit -- T-SQL's defaults for parameters are restricted to constants. You cannot use `GETUTCDATE()`. You can, confusingly, use `GETUTCDATE`, but that will actually use the string `'GETUTCDATE'` as a default. This is slightly related to your question in that you appear to be asking if you can make it so that EF can detect that the value `0001-01-01` (i.e. `default(DateTime)`) was not changed, but should also not be propagated to the database since it's not the "real" value -- which looks like an impossibility to me. (But I'm by no means an EF expert.)